# Binding bulk records to the select dropdown with infinite scroll using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have millions of record which I need to fetch and bind it to my select dropdown in my angularjs application. But, as we know obviously it'll cause the performance issue. So I'm looking for the serious solution as like a ui-grid infinite scroll functionality in select dropdown.

**HTML Template:**

```
<select ng-model="zipCode" ng-options="zip.FZIP as zip.FZIP for zip in zipCodes | limitTo: totalDisplayed" ng-init="zipCodeInit()" ng-change="loadMore(totalDisplayed);"></select>
```

**Controller Code:**

```
$scope.totalDisplayed =1000;
$scope.loadMore = function (startCount) {
   var endCount=startCount + 1000;
   $http.get('api/get-zip-codes?rowStartCount=startCount&rowEndCount=endCount').then(function(response){
      $scope.data = $scope.data + response.data;
      $scope.totalDisplayed += 1000;  
   });
};
```

Here my problem is to make a call to loadmore function on scroll of my select dropdown. My current implementation is ng-change.

Any Idea or the solution will be helpful to make my expected change on this select dropdown.

Comment: use md-virtual repeat . thats use for your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realise that we can't have such dynamic dropdown to load data on scroll and this was the requirement because of bulk records such 2Lakhs+ records to be listed. And to overcome this problem I have used predictive search/auto complete text box which works with me perfectly based on the user input. 
Thanks for the Answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use this jQuery plugin it will help you

http://jscroll.com/

Comment: Thanks @Akshay Annadate. I'm expecting it to done it with angularjs itself not with jQuery. It would be great if you share any Idea in angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [Solution For Very Long Dropdown Menus](https://css-tricks.com/long-dropdowns-solution/).

This would help, it has all the code as well visuals.

Comment: Yeah Thanks @Akshy Soam I've seen your link which is jQuery. Don't we have solution in angularjs itself?